# Edit the centroid of a polygon

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon in a donut shape (see purple polygon) whose centroid falls under a different polygon. How can I modify its centroid? I tried with the RealCentroid plugin, which created a new centroid (see the point in the image) but I still don't know how to make this new point the centroid of the polygon.

[image]

Comment: You can't modify a centroid, since the centroid of a polygon is mathematically defined. Please be more specific on what you already did and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: A center-of-mass centroid cannot be changed without significant changes to the geometry.  A *label point* is a location which is within the geometry bounds.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: What do you want to do with the centroid so that the point needs to be on the polygon surface?

Comment: QGIS has a tool called Point on surface within the Vector-Geometry tools which might produce a result you need.

Comment: Or use pole of inaccessability